# Styling Cell in DataGrid according to its value

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` with values. I want to check each cell and if the value is not between two numbers (limits), I want to change the background to red. The limits are different for each column of the `DataGrid`. I am trying to achieve it by changing the `ColumnStyle` in `OnAutoGeneratingColumn` method of the `DataGrid`, but so far I am not successful. Could you please have a look what is wrong with my code?

The  `OnAutoGeneratingColumn` method:

```
protected override void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {

            //The first yolumn with date I dont want to alter
            if (Columns.Count == 0)
            {
                base.OnAutoGeneratedColumns(e);
            }
            else {
                //Trigger to chech if the number is lower than the bottom limit
                DataTrigger lowerTrigger = new DataTrigger();
                lowerTrigger.Binding = new Binding("Content")
                {
                    Converter = new LessThanConverter(),
                    ConverterParameter = SelectedDevices[this.Columns.Count - 1].minValue
                };
                lowerTrigger.Value = "True";
                lowerTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Red));


                //Trigger to check if the number is higher than the top limit
                DataTrigger higherTrigger = new DataTrigger();
                higherTrigger.Binding = new Binding("Content")
                {
                    Converter = new LessThanConverter(),
                    ConverterParameter = SelectedDevices[this.Columns.Count - 1].maxValue
                };
                higherTrigger.Value = "False";
                higherTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Red));


                //Multi triger to check, whether the number is between the tow limits
                MultiDataTrigger betweenTrigger = new MultiDataTrigger();
                Condition conditionMin = new Condition();
                conditionMin.Binding = new Binding("Content")
                {
                    Converter = new LessThanConverter(),
                    ConverterParameter = SelectedDevices[this.Columns.Count-1].minValue
                };
                conditionMin.Value = "False";

                Condition conditionMax = new Condition();
                conditionMax.Binding = new Binding("Content")
                {
                    Converter = new LessThanConverter(),
                    ConverterParameter = SelectedDevices[this.Columns.Count - 1].maxValue
                };
                conditionMax.Value = "True";

                betweenTrigger.Conditions.Add(conditionMax);
                betweenTrigger.Conditions.Add(conditionMin);

                betweenTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Blue));

                Style style = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
                style.Triggers.Add(lowerTrigger);
                //style.Triggers.Add(betweenTrigger);
                style.Triggers.Add(higherTrigger);

                e.Column.CellStyle = style;

                base.OnAutoGeneratedColumns(e);
            }
        }
```

The `LessThanConverter` class:

```
public class LessThanConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
            object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {

            double dValue = System.Convert.ToDouble(value);
            double dParameter = System.Convert.ToDouble(parameter);

            return (dValue <= dParameter);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
            object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using XAML?  It seems a declarative approach would be better rather than the procedural code you supplied.

Comment: I was trying to do so, but wasn't able to figure out how to pass different limits to each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally I found the solution. My mistake was, that it is not possible to bind the value for the convertor as I did `new Binding("Content")`. The correct solution is to bind it to the name of the column, that could be accomplished on runtime with `e.Column.Header.ToString()`, than it is working!